# DataContext.Refresh not refreshing the object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a datacontext where I after communicating with the database performs the following operation:

```
private DAL.Client _client;
public void ReloadCurrentClient()
        {
            DBContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, _client);
        }
```

I expected this method to bring the client-object back to sync with the database, but for some reason _client.Relationship (which is a collection of relationships) is not updated. Can you please give me some input on where I am off track here?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ReloadCurrentClient()
        {
            DBContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues,DBContext.Clients );

        }
```

try this 2nd parameter is object entity.I think DBContext is your Data Context Object & Client is your table name.When you write DAL & press . after that you will see it automatically add 's' into your table name.so use like 
DBContext.Clients.
I hope it works for you.

Comment: Doesnt this mean that its updating ALL clients? This would probably work if you have 100 clients, but not when you have a lot more than that..

Comment: Exactly.. That means that this will not be a good solution.. I only need to update the client that I'm currently working with..

Comment: But it doesn't update the associated navigation collection property which maps to another table. It is updating only the properties which map to the column of the table to which the current Entity points to. Is there a way out of this? My issue is also regarding Linq to SQL.